# helm accessing rego files inside templates

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, open-policy-agent, rego

I am following example mentioned in https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/.

I am able to load toml files in configmap, but when I use rego files, I am getting an error:

```sh
cat multiple_config.yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "label-check.rego" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
    {{ $files.Get . }}
  {{- end }}
```

```sh
Error :-
Error: YAML parse error on opa/templates/multiple_config.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: could not find expected ':'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing [is a common issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2004) . It's probably an indentation inconsistency in your rego file. You can see in this example that rego [can perfectly be used in ConfigMaps](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/v0.12.2/kubernetes-admission-control/#3-deploy-opa-on-top-of-kubernetes).

You could try this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range tuple "label-check.rego" }}
  {{ . }}: |-
{{ $files.Get . | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```

✌️

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory can you accept it? Thanks!